# What do the Kanfei HaOkets look like?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, rambam, slaughter-shochet-shecht, kedusha-holiness

So from what I understand in the Rambam Sefer Kedusha Hilchot MaAchalot Asurot Halacha 3 it says if you find an animal which you can't check if its kosher by checking it's mouth to see if it chews it's cud  or by checking it's feet to see if it has split hoves because both mouth and feet were cut off... after the animal is ritually slaughtered, you should instead check the tip of its tail(the kanfei HaOkets) and if you find that the meat splits there or crosses it is kosher. (אִם מָצָא בְּשָׂרָהּ שָׁם מַהֲלַךְ שְׁתִי וָעֵרֶב טְהוֹרָה)

is there someone who might have a picture or drawing of how this is suppose to look like?

Source:
https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Foods.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en